# Can I get Apex Launcher's scrolling background to work on EMUI 4.1?

Tags: huawei, wallpaper, live-wallpaper, apex-launcher-pro

I got my new Honor 8 this past Monday, and after extensive tweaking (including hair pulling and uttering of words not approriate in respectable company), I got it to work and look the way I want it to, except for one thing. The scrolling background of Apex Launcher simply refuses to work. I've browsed through the system settings and the Apex settings until I've gone blind. I've tried to change the background setting of Apex to non-scrolling, restarting, changing it back to scrolling and restarting again, but I simply can't find a way to get this working. Is there a way?

I'm using [Wallpaper Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.wallpaperChanger) as live background, but I've tried disabling it, and instead using EMUI's native function to randomly change the background image, but this makes no difference. I've also tried setting Wallpaper Changer to use static background rather than live background. This also makes no difference. The image is cropped to the physical screen resolution (1080x1920) and the leftmost part of it shown on all screens.

For example, this image

[image]

is shown like this, regardless of which screen I'm on

[image]

I've rooted, and because of issues with TWRP and SuperSU on EMUI 5.0, I won't upgrade until those are resolved.

I'm not in any way affilated with with any software mentioned above, I'm simply a user. The images above have been created by myself, and you are free to download and use them as you see fit.

UPDATE: This suddenly started working. I don't know what fixed it, so I don't think this can be classified as an answer. It started working after I shut down to replace the SIM, because the transfer of my number from my old carrier to my new one had just been done. After booting up again, the scrolling background was working. As far as I can remember, I had changed no settings since I last rebooted. I did receive an update to Wallpaper Changer, but that came **after** the scrolling background had already started working, and the changelog only mentions adding the ability to darken the wallpaper. A mystery, but I'll leave it at that, unless someone has any ideas about what has happened here.

Comment: Can't say specifically about the launcher but bear in mind that Huawei tweaks the OS very heavily to the extent some apps just don't behave the way they are supposed to- especially those interacting with UI. Not surprising. IMO, options are use a launcher that suits the phone you, or browse Chinese forums for a modded launcher and use that at your risk

Comment: @beeshyams I'm aware of Huawei tweaking the OS, and I decided to go with the Honor anyway. And considering that I got it to work the way I want, apart from the scrolling bg, I don't regret it. And with the options you presented, I will live with the non-scrolling bg.

Comment: Earlier device of mine was Honor 6, and it had problems with Xposed framework too involving UI- suggest research that if you are going to use Xposed

Comment: @beeshyams I've tried Xposed in the past, both on my S3 and my S5, but I've never found any modules for which I actually had any real use, so I hadn't even considered trying it now. Still, it's good to know that it may be problematic, and that I need to properly reasearch it if I do decide to use it. Thanks.